# Как ограничить время выполнения задачи в python?

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть сервер на котором установлен python 3, Flask, там же установлено python приложение, которое из ssh запускается командой

> myapp arg1 arg2

и после выполнения отдает json

Мне нужно делать GET запрос к этому серверу и получать результат, для этого я установил Flask

И с других серверов я делаю cURL запрос на сервер с питон-приложением, таймаут cURL запроса у меня 30 сек. Бывает так что за 30 сек я не получаю ответ, потому что на сервер пришло слишком много запросов, и он ничего не возвращает, и уже cURL соединение закрывается, а питон-приложение все равно продолжает работу и потребляет оперативную память.

вот код моего server.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import subprocess

@app.route("/get/<arg1>")
def get_json(arg1):
    result = subprocess.run(['myapp', 'test', arg1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return result
```

то есть когда приходит GET скрипт запускает **subprocess.run*** с приложением, и ждем его выполнения и возвращает результат.

я хотел бы сделать, чтобы если за 30 сек. не получили результат, то чтобы субпроцесс завершился принудительно. но именно тот субпроцесс который запущен текущим GET запросом, а не все суброцессы убить, потому что одновременно на сервер может приходить несколько GET запросов.

Буду благодарен за помощь. Я в питон новичок, прошу не ругать сильно :)

Comment: [Popen.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), [Popen.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill)

Comment: https://ostechnix.com/run-command-specific-time-linux/    `timeout 30s myapp arg1 arg2`

Comment: @Chorkov думаю это подойдет! помогите пожалуйста правильно вставить переменную сюда `subprocess.run(['timeout', '{$variable}s' 'myapp', 'test', arg1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: `['timeout', f'{variable}s' 'myapp', 'test', arg1]`  - если хотите считать локальную переменную из python